# Ifs and elifs wont work properly in roulette game - python

Tags: python, random, if-statement, python-3.x, int

Ok so I am making a roulette game. The random number that the spinner lands on is called 'figure'. It is a very basic and simple code but it won't seem to work for me properly. 
At the moment you either pick a specific number or choose 1 - 18. I've tried many different ways and still no luck. Here is my code. If anyone knows what the problem is please let me know. Thanks:

```
numbers = ['1', '2', '3'.......'35', '36']

figure = choice(numbers)

d = textinput("Pick bet", "")

if int(figure) > 18 and d == '1-18' or '1 - 18' or '1- 18' or '1 -18':
    pu()
    goto(100,100)
    write("Loser", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 30, "bold"))

elif int(figure) < 19 and d == '1-18' or '1 - 18' or '1- 18' or '1 -18':
    pu()
    goto(10,100)
    write("Well done", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 30, "bold"))


elif int(d) in range(36) and int(figure) == int(d):
    pu()
    goto(100,100)
    write("Well done", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 30, "bold"))

elif int(d) in range(36) and int(figure) != int(d):
    pu()
    goto(100,100)
    write("Loser", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 30, "bold"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at:

```
if int(figure) > 18 and d == '1-18' or '1 - 18' or '1- 18' or '1 -18':
```

Here you have several statements that always evaluate to True; each of `'1 - 18' or '1- 18' or '1 -18'` is a a non-empty string. It doesn't matter what values `int(figure)` or `d` have. This means python sees that line as the equivalent of `if something or True`.

What you want to do instead is use the `in` operator to test if your `d` is part of a list of options:

```
if int(figure) > 18 and d in ('1-18', '1 - 18', '1- 18', '1 -18'):
```

The same problem applies to your `elif` statement.

Comment: Thanks a million. Worked perfectly. Very simple mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Python thinks the following:

```
if (int(figure) > 18 and d == '1-18') or '1 - 18' or '1- 18' ...
```

Boolean operators have a lower precedence than comparison operators so the code is not doing what you intended. Instead the strings at the end are each interpreted as operands of `or` and thus interpreted as a boolean value, which is always `True` in this case.

You can rewrite it in the following way:

```
if int(figure) > 18 and d in ['1-18', '1 - 18', '1- 18', '1 -18']
```

or probably even removing spaces from the string so you only need to compare against a single value:

```
if int(figure) > 18 and d.replace(' ', '') == '1-18'
```

Comment: Note that if `d` is `'1 - 1  8'` that might be an error as far as the OP is concerned, but the `d.replace` case makes it a valid answer. Probably not a problem, but worth noting.

Comment: Indeed, yes, a regex replace would probably be a better choice, but I had to look up every single detail of this answer already and `string.replace` was quicker to find than `re.replace` ;-)